# In LMDB, does a transaction read the value it just wrote, or the old value?

Tags: lmdb

a transaction provides a consistent view of the data. now if there's an RW transaction, which has acquired a handle and is currently operating, if it changes a key, and reads it back, later, within the same transaction, but before commiting or aborting, will it read the old value or the value it just wrote?

Answer (score 0):

It will read the value it just wrote.